# can influxdb perform math between series like graphite/timelion?

Tags: graphite, influxdb

If I have two different types of metrics such as visits and server load, can I combine those two series (eg, visitor/server load) to detect anomalies (eg, server load of 5 might be ok if I have 1k visits/second but a sign that something is wrong if I have 500 v/s).

In graphite (and now timelion), I can perform math on arbitrary series to compare them.  AFAIK, in something like grafana, all the math you can do with graphite series is a part of the graphite backend.  And timelion does it all client side, but there isn't a influx plugin yet.

Does influx have the ability to combine/compare arbitrary series like this?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, no. InfluxDB alone doesn't support doing this kind of logic. Joins will be added in the future though.

However, you could use both InfluxDB and [Kapacitor](https://github.com/influxdata/kapacitor) together to achieve what you're trying to do. Particularly you'd use the [Join node](http://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v0.13/nodes/join_node/) in Kapacitor.

Answer (score 0):

Or run an API on top of influxdb that does support multi-series operations, like [Graphite-API](https://github.com/brutasse/graphite-api) and its influxdb storage finder, [InfluxGraph](https://github.com/InfluxGraph/influxgraph).

Graphite API has functions that act across series, for the specific example, see [sumSeries](http://graphite-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite_api.functions.sumSeries).